# Python3 delete n amount of elements in list after every loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

I can request the stock of 250 products at once. There are around about 7500-8000 products, but the amount changes by the day. So I try to request 250 products, delete them and do this again until my list(all_sku) holds less than 250 items in it, so I know this is my last request.

Sounds pretty easy, but today e.g there are 7697 items, but I only get stock for 7250 items.

```py
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0, 40):
    all_values = []
    time_now = time.time()
    time.sleep(10)
    if time_now - start_time >= 480:
        stock_values = xxx.get_stockforitems(all_sku[:250], session_master)
        all_values.append(stock_values)
        print(len(all_sku), 'before deleting first 250 elements')
        del all_sku[:250]
        print(len(all_sku), 'after deleting first 250 elements')
    else:
        stock_values = xxx.get_stockforitems(all_sku[:250], session_master)
        all_values.append(stock_values)
        print(len(all_sku), 'before deleting first 250 elements')
        del all_sku[:250]
        print(len(all_sku), 'after deleting first 250 elements')
    if len(all_sku) <= 250:
        stock_values = xxx.get_stockforitems(all_sku[:len(all_sku)], session_master)
        all_values.append(stock_values)
        print(len(all_sku), 'values remaining')
        del all_sku[:len(all_sku)]
        print(len(all_sku), 'after deleting elements')
        break
```

console output:

```
1187 before deleting first 250 elements
937 after deleting first 250 elements
937 before deleting first 250 elements
687 after deleting first 250 elements
687 before deleting first 250 elements
437 after deleting first 250 elements
437 before deleting first 250 elements
187 after deleting first 250 elements
187 values remaining
0 after deleting elements
```

Probably the error is in the `if < 250` condition

It's my first time working with `break` statement, maybe there is my origin of all evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok and the output seems to be as expected.
My guess will be that perhaps you are not getting all the results from `get_stockforitems`. I would add printouts of how many items you get each time.

There are some issues with your code that does not affect correctness: the if and else branches seem identical. Why are they there? The `range(0, 40)` seems random - why not `while len(all_sku) > 0:`.

Also all this deleting business seems messy, why not

```
for i in range(0,len(all_sku),250): 
   batch = all_sku[i:i+250]
   get_stockforitems(batch...
```

Comment: Hoi mate,  your suggestion helped me out :) I still sticked to my range instead of while, but your ```for i in range(0,len(all_sku),250): 
   batch = all_sku[i:i+250]
   get_stockforitems(batch...``` was very good for me :)

Comment: So, what was the problem?

Comment: my parts where I deleted the elements in list, after I sent a request

Comment: Don't see the problem there, but as long as it works now ...